# Class hierarchy not fitting inheritance model

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

I want to create a class  named “Activity” which will have properties like ActivityID, ActivityText,Image… etc. Now, users can post Comments on this activity and also LIKE/UNLIKE a activity.

ActivityClass --

```
// Activity.m
 #import "Activity.h"

@implementation Activity


@synthesize id = _id;

- (void)setActivityMessage {
    NSLog(@“New Activity message ");
}
@end
```

LikeUnlike Class—

```
// LikeUnlike.m
 #import "LikeUnlike.h"
@implementation LikeUnlike

- (void)likeActivity {
    NSLog(@“ likeActivity
 message ");
}

- (void)unlikeActivity {
    NSLog(@“ unlikeActivity
 message ");
}
@end
```

Comments Class --

```
// Comments.m
 #import "Comments.h"
@implementation Comments

- (void)addComment {
    NSLog(@“ addComment ");
}
- (void)editComment {
    NSLog(@“ editComment ");
}
- (void)deleteComment {
    NSLog(@“ deleteComment");
}
@end
```

The hierarchy of  the classes is something like Activity—> LikeUnlike & Activity —> Comments

I have knowledge about Inheritance but my case does not suit for subclassing  ActivityClass into LikeUnlikeClass and CommentsClass.

Can anyone please help on which strategy to use for maintaining  this hierarchy..?

Comment: `but my case does not suit for subclassing ActivityClass into LikeUnlikeClass and CommentsClass.` Then why do you **need** this hierarchy of classes that your models obviously don't fit? Seems to me that Like/Unlike should be methods on `Activity` and each `Activity` object should have some property that holds`Comment` objects. From your description, there is no subclassing involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to do any complex subclassing of the classes for your scenario. But, just for your information when you want some methods to be just a part of your class rather than creating the new class as subclass you can use the CATEGORY.

In your case also, if you want to separate the PostComment class make it a category of Activity Class.
For more information on Category read from here http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/categories , it explains Category - its implementation, uses,etc.